# Large swf file player

Tags: windows-xp, swf

I have a large (442Mb) swf file containing a movie. I have found several swf players that can play it, but they all suffer the same problem. The progress slider does not seem to represent the full length of the movie. This means that when I move the slider I can only select to jump to various parts of the first 10 minutes... If I want to see any other parts I have to sit and watch from the beginning. Do you think the file is corrupt? Or is this somehow a feature of swf files?

The movie is a long academic lecture that I am studying - I want to make notes and listen to assorted parts (near the end) repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kind of stupid to make a SWF like that. Theres a limit on some encoders like SUPER which will only make 10 minute swf-files.

Try this tool here: http://www.sothink.com/page/swf-decompiler/extract-flv/how-to-extract-flv.htm
You can extract the raw flash movie (FLV) with it and play that in any media player. (Mplayer Classic for example)

Comment: There is always problems when you try to embed that much video inside a swf. Believe me I have tried. Max number of frames in a flash is 16000 (about 11 minutes) at 24fps. You can stuff more video in it but as you see this leads to problems.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said it's stupid to do this. Better have a SWF with a proper progress bar for the video and a FLV on the side. Even if it has 440 MB. Works fine that way.